# Blender proportional edit slider gone in 2.8 and above?

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I'm using a Wacom tablet and don't have a scroll wheel to adjust spread of my vertex proportional edit selection.  My other option are the PageUp PageDwn buttons. I would love to find the Proportional Edit slider that was around in older version of Blender but it doesn't seem to be there is 2.8 and up.

Any pen tablet users have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution discovered by OP:**

I found a great solution. On my Wacom Intuos Pro pen tablet, my touch ring set to "ZOOM" is a perfect substitute to a mouse scroll wheel. Anyone using a pen tablet (with a touch ring) instead of a mouse can do this to adjust the spread of the proportional edit! Problem solved

**For those whom this solution does not help:**

The slider can be found in the *Operator Panel*. You can only adjust the size after the fact though (as far as I know), and the selection circle is not visible, so it's not ideal. Nevertheless it's there:

[image: PorEdit]

Comment: Whoah.  I'd given up on a slider but there it is.  Thank you!  Love your custom theme BTW.

Comment: Or you can pop a floating window with the same info by pressing F9

Comment: Thanks.  The problem is what Christopher Bennett pointed out.  F9 only brings up the proportional edit Operator Panel *after* you execute a transform to your selected verts.  

To adjust the size of the Prop Edit spread *during* your transform, you need the scroll wheel or PgUp/PgDwn.

I'm either going to remap PgUp/PgDwn somewhere on the left side of keyboard so I don't have to go over to where those keys are, or I'm just going to suck it up and reach over to the PgUp/PgDwn buttons every time I need to change size of Prop Edit spread.

Comment: I found a great solution.  On my Wacom Intuos Pro pen tablet, my touch ring set to "ZOOM" is a perfect substitute to a mouse scroll wheel.  

Anyone using a pen tablet (with a touch ring) instead of a mouse can do this to adjust the spread of the proportional edit!  Problem solved.

Comment: Hey. That's great you found a solution. If it's ok with you, I'll copy your comment into the answer to help future users.